# Python Threading: What functions run in which thread

Tags: python, multithreading, psycopg2, race-condition

So I have a pyhthon application which im attempting to emulate a queue line up system. It import a library and calls to that library, specificaly psycopg2. An example code is as below

```
import threading,queue,psycopg2

q = queue.Queue()

def workerChecker():
  while True:#Keeps the thread always checking for new things in queue
    item = q.get()
    addItemToDb(item) <------This part 
    q.task_done()

threading.Thread(target=workerChecker, daemon=True).start()

def addItemToDb(item):
  #Do something and use psycopg2 to insert item to db here
```

So I can't seem to find a clear answer online on which thread will the codes in addItemToDb run in.

More specifically, will all the codes in the function addItemToDb be restricted to execution within the same thread as workerChecker ? Given that it uses an imported library.

Any assistance or help will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

The code inside `addItemToDb` will be restricted to the thread that runs `workerChecker` as long as it is called only by that function, but it can be used anywhere outside that thread in the main thread or any other thread that you create.

If you want to make sure that only `workerChecker` has access to that function you could define `addItemToDb` inside `workerChecker`

```
def workerChecker():
    def addItemToDb(item):
        # addItemToDb definition
        pass
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        addItemToDb(item)
        q.task_done()
```